# Anime involving a survival game in a dungeon with deadly traps

Tags: story-identification, anime

I found this in a short YouTube (death scenes list) video, but I can't find the video again, and I didn't really get a grasp of what it was about.
From the looks of it, it's kind of like a survival game where people are having to get through a dungeon or underground facility, that happens to be full of traps. It almost looks like this place is actively trying to kill them as later on a cute thing flows down a stream, causing one of the characters to jump in after it only to fall down a waterfall, almost like it was meant for her.

There are also traps like falling floors, (I think there was a hall full of lasers as well), and I believe even axes coming out of walls. It also looked like a competition, might have even had teams, as some characters seemed determined to kill one another. Sorry for the horrible description, but I'm hoping this should be enough. It looked really interesting and am hoping to watch it, I just can't figure out what it was called.

I tried looking up things like "Anime with death dungeons", or "Anime like the hunger games" but to no avail.

Comment: [There's an Anime.SE](http://anime.stackexchange.com) that would probably be better suited for this question.

Comment: @jwodder We were being overrun with low quality identification questions over at Anime.SE, so we've banned them. This question would not be welcome there anymore; it would be closed and deleted.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm running out of luck for this. I'd hate to be a nuisance, so are there any other places I could try, or just give up?

Comment: @Ben To my knowledge, your question is still on-topic here at SciFi & Fantasy; jwodder was just suggesting you might have more luck on a site for anime experts than on a site for general sci-fi and fantasy experts like this one. If you do want to seek out anime specialists, the forums at MyAnimeList and AnimeSuki will field identification questions like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The anime in question is [Angel Beats!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_Beats!)

The deaths you mention (like hall of lasers and cute thing in the river) occur in the second episode.

### Death Compilation

The dungeon is the pathway to an organization called the Guild, and is filled with traps to prevent the character known as Angel from reaching the Guild.

Comment: The laser corridor is a total ripoff of Resident Evil.

Comment: [You're welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM).

Comment: That's the one! Thank you so much!